# Using different classes for different links in d3 js in tree layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I am using [d3 collapsible layout](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083)  to make a collapsible tree. I want the links in the tree to have different colors according to json data.

The json data is

```
    {"root":{
 "name": "A",
 "branchid" : 2,
 "active" : true,
 "activecount" : 3, 
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "Data1",
   "branchid" : 2,
   "active" : false,
   "activecount" : 3, 
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "C",
     "branchid" : 2,
     "active" : true,
     "activecount" : 3, 
     "children": [
      {"name": "D","branchid" : 2, "active" : true,"activecount" : 3},
      {"name": "D","branchid" : 2, "active" : false,"activecount" : 3},
      {"name": "D","branchid" : 2, "active" : false,"activecount" : 3},
      {"name": "D","branchid" : 2, "active" : true,"activecount" : 3}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "C",
     "branchid" : 2,
     "active" : true,
     "activecount" : 3,
     "children": [
      {"name": "D","branchid" : 2, "active" : true,"activecount" : 3},
      {"name": "D","branchid" : 2, "active" : false,"activecount" : 3},
      {"name": "D","branchid" : 2, "active" : true,"activecount" : 3},
      {"name": "D","branchid" : 2, "active" : false,"activecount" : 3},
      {"name": "D","branchid" : 2, "active" : true,"activecount" : 3}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "C",
     "branchid" : 2,
     "active" : false,
     "activecount" : 3,
     "children": [
      {"name": "D","branchid" : 2, "active" : true,"activecount" : 3}
     ]
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Data2",
   "branchid" : 2,
   "active" : true,
   "activecount" : 3,
   "children": [
    {"name": "D","branchid" : 2, "active" : true,"activecount" : 3},
    {"name": "D","branchid" : 2, "active" : false,"activecount" : 3},
    {
     "name": "C",
     "branchid" : 2,
     "active" : false,
     "activecount" : 3,
     "children": [
      {"name": "D","branchid" : 2, "active" : true,"activecount" : 3},
      {"name": "D","branchid" : 2, "active" : false,"activecount" : 3},
      {"name": "D","branchid" : 2, "active" : true,"activecount" : 3},
      {"name": "D","branchid" : 2, "active" : false,"activecount" : 3},
      {"name": "D","branchid" : 2, "active" : true,"activecount" : 3},
      {"name": "D","branchid" : 2, "active" : false,"activecount" : 3},
      {"name": "D","branchid" : 2, "active" : true,"activecount" : 3},
      {"name": "D","branchid" : 2, "active" : false,"activecount" : 3},
      {"name": "D","branchid" : 2, "active" : true,"activecount" : 3}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "C","branchid" : 2, "active" : false,"activecount" : 3},
    {"name": "C","branchid" : 2, "active" : false,"activecount" : 3},
    {"name": "C","branchid" : 2, "active" : false,"activecount" : 3},
    {"name": "C","branchid" : 2, "active" : true,"activecount" : 3},
    {"name": "C","branchid" : 2, "active" : false,"activecount" : 3},
    {"name": "C","branchid" : 2, "active" : true,"activecount" : 3},
    {"name": "C","branchid" : 2, "active" : true,"activecount" : 3},
    {"name": "C","branchid" : 2, "active" : false,"activecount" : 3},
    {"name": "C","branchid" : 2, "active" : true,"activecount" : 3}
   ]
  }
 ]
}}
```

I want the link to have `activebranch` css class if the `active` property of target node is true, otherwise it should have `link` css class.

```
.activebranch{
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 3.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.link{
   fill: none;
   stroke: #bbb;
   stroke-width: 3.5px;
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

I am using following code to do this, but it dosen't work.

```
 var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
              .data(links, function(d) {
                  if(d.target.active == "false")
                    return d.target.id; 
                });
          var activelink = svg.selectAll("path.activebranch")
                  .data(links, function(d){
                      if(d.target.active == "true")
                        return  d.target.id;
                  });

          // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
          link.enter().insert("path", "g")
              .attr("class", "link")
              .attr("d", function(d) {
                var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
                return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
              })
              .on("click", TimeLine);

            activelink.enter().insert("path", "g")
              .attr("class", "activebranch")
              .attr("d", function(d) {
                var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
                return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
              })
              .on("click", TimeLine);

          // Transition links to their new position.
          link.transition()
              .duration(duration)
              .attr("d", diagonal);

          activelink.transition()
              .duration(duration)
              .attr("d", diagonal);

          // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
          link.exit().transition()
              .duration(duration)
              .attr("d", function(d) {
                var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
                return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
              })
              .remove();
           activelink.exit().transition()
              .duration(duration)
              .attr("d", function(d) {
                var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
                return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
              })
              .remove();
```

I am using css class `activelink` for those links which have `"active" : true` and css class `link` which have `"active" : false`.

Comment: Why not just add all links with `.attr('class', function(d) {return (d.active ? 'activelink' : 'link');}` or in ES6: `.attr('class', d => (d.active ? 'activelink' : 'link'))` ? I think that should work, if I understand correctly...

Comment: If I do that, I will also have to select class in `selectAll`  function (in the first line) is  according to `d.active`.                                                                   `var link = svg.selectAll(function(d){ return (d.target.active === "true" ? 'path.activebranch' : 'path.link');})`

Comment: But this shows following error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'active' of undefined`

Comment: or you add multiple classes, like a basic `link` class (which you can select upon) and as an add-on the `activeLink` class. Might be helpful to have a fiddle or something to try it :)

Comment: I made a fiddle....but it dosen't work....the code is in this link - http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083

Comment: While I make the fiddle correctly.....try it using the above link....srry for the trouble. Link of fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/sqow70mj/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your fiddle I created [this](http://jsfiddle.net/chroth/sqow70mj/2/).

To make it work, I first changed the raw json link, and then I added a sample additional class:

```
.link2 {
    stroke: red;
}
```

So when I add a link (on `enter`), I simply:

```
link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", function (d) {
        var myClass = (d.target.name.length > 7 ? "" : " link2");
        return "link" + myClass;
    })
    ...etc
```

so I make sure the base class `link` is still there, and if a certain criteria is met (in our case here: if the name of the target node is > 7 in length) I add a class (or not). So in our case, we now have certain red links, based on the data in the JSON.

I hope this gets you started with your own data!

(add a `console.log(d)` in the function pasted above, to see the data that you have on the link).